# Add a button to page

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I'm trying to add a button next to some Text which when clicked will bring the address up on google maps.  The problem is that it's just adding the text of my button but not the button itself.

```
function googleMaps(address) {
    GM_openInTab('https://maps.google.com/maps?q=' + address.replace(/ /g, '+'));
}

function addButtons() {
    var mydiv         = document.querySelector('div[data-bind="CurrentJob.addr"]');
    var address       = mydiv.textContent + ", UT";
    mydiv.textContent = address + ' <input type="button" id="mapButton" value="Google Maps">';

    document.body.appendChild (mydiv.textContent);
    document.getElementById ("mapButton").addEventListener ("click", googleMaps(address), false);
}
```

I'm sure it has something to do with the 2nd last line, but I'm still pretty new to this stuff.

---

***Updated code:***

The button is added, but the event is fired on page load.  Clicking it thereafter does nothing.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name    Job Aids
// @description Aid in closing tickets
// @include https://techaccess.ad.qintra.com/WorkJobs/WorkJobs.aspx*
// @namespace   camzilla.net
// @version     1.1.20121128
// ==/UserScript==

var url  = window.location.href.split(".aspx");
var page = url[1].toLowerCase();

if (page == "#finaltest") {
    window.addEventListener ("load", finalResults, false);
} else if (page == "#threetoneslope") {
    window.addEventListener ("load", toneSlopeResults, false);
} else if (page == "#codes") {
    window.addEventListener ("load", closingComments, false);
} else if (page == "#cras") {
    window.addEventListener ("load", crasResults, false);
} else if (page == "#jobinfo") {
    window.addEventListener ("load", addButtons, false);
}

function googleMaps(address) {
    GM_openInTab('https://maps.google.com/maps?q=' + address.replace(/ /g, '+'));
}

function pollDSLAM(address) {
    GM_openInTab('http://acmspjv1.interprise.com/cgi-bin/QC/DSL/dslam6100Int.pl?telephoneNum=' + address);
}

function addButtons() {
    var mydiv   = document.querySelector('div[data-bind="CurrentJob.addr"]');
    var address = mydiv.textContent + ", UT";
    var btn     = document.createElement("input");
    with (btn) {
        id    ='mapButton';
        type  ='button';
        value ='Get Map';
        addEventListener("click", googleMaps(address), true);
    }
    mydiv.appendChild(btn);

    mydiv   = document.querySelector('div[data-bind="CurrentJob.cktid"]');
    btn     = document.createElement("input");
    with (btn) {
        id    ='dslButton';
        type  ='button';
        value ='Poll Dslam';
        addEventListener("click", pollDSLAM(mydiv.textContent), true);
    }
    mydiv.appendChild(btn);
}

function setCookie(c_name, value, exdays) {
    var exdate=new Date();
    exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
    var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
    document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
}

function getCookie(c_name) {
    var i,x,y,ARRcookies=document.cookie.split(";");

    for (i=0;i<ARRcookies.length;i++) {

        x=ARRcookies[i].substr(0,ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
        y=ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=")+1);
        x=x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");

        if (x==c_name) {
            return unescape(y);
        }
    }

    return null;
}

function finalResults() {
    var dc, current, loss, noise, pi, lb;

    dc      = getRandom(51, 49, 2);   
    current = getRandom(37, 29, 2);
    loss    = getRandom(7, 2, 2);
    noise   = getRandom(7, 1, 2);
    pi      = getRandom(67, 60, 2);
    lb      = getRandom(79, 70, 2);

    document.getElementById('finalTestInsightNo').click();

    document.getElementById("finalTestBeforeAcTg").value        = "0.00";
    document.getElementById("finalTestBeforeAcRg").value        = "0.00";
    document.getElementById("finalTestBeforeAcTr").value        = "0.00";
    document.getElementById("finalTestBeforeDcTr").value        = dc;
    document.getElementById("finalTestBeforeDcTg").value        = "0.00";
    document.getElementById("finalTestBeforeDcRg").value        = dc;
    document.getElementById("finalTestBeforeLoopCurrent").value = current;
    document.getElementById("finalTestAfterLoss").value         = loss;
    document.getElementById("finalTestAfterNoise").value        = noise;
    document.getElementById("finalTestAfterPi").value           = pi;
    document.getElementById("finalTestAfterLb").value           = lb;

    document.getElementById("finalTestAfterLb").focus();
    window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight-250);

    // Store cookies to be used on cras page if needed
    setCookie("loss", loss, 1);
    setCookie("pi", pi, 1);
    setCookie("current", current, 1);
    setCookie("noise", noise, 1);
    setCookie("lb", lb, 1);
}

function crasResults() {
    document.getElementById("crasCircuitLoss").value    = getCookie("loss");
    document.getElementById("crasPowerInfluence").value = getCookie("pi");
    document.getElementById("crasLineCurrent").value    = getCookie("current");
    document.getElementById("crasCircuitNoise").value   = getCookie("noise");
    document.getElementById("crasBalance").value        = getCookie("lb");

    document.getElementById('crasFoundInF2').click();
}

function toneSlopeResults() {
    var dc = getRandom(51, 49, 2);   

    document.getElementById("ToneSlopeInsightNo").click();
    document.getElementById("ToneSlopeDmarcTaggedYes").click();
    document.getElementById("ToneSlopeClecDtPresentYes").click();

    document.getElementById("ToneSlopeBeforeDcTr").value    = dc;
    document.getElementById("ToneSlopeBeforeDcTg").value    = "0.00";
    document.getElementById("ToneSlopeBeforeDcRg").value    = dc;   
    document.getElementById("ToneSlopeRingbackTr").value    = getRandom(90,85,2);
    document.getElementById("ToneSlopeAfterResistTg").value = getRandom(998,20,0);
    document.getElementById("ToneSlopeAfterResistRg").value = getRandom(998,20,0);
    document.getElementById("ToneSlopeAfterResistTr").value = getRandom(998,20,0);

    document.getElementById("ToneSlopeAfter404").value      = "0.00";
    document.getElementById("ToneSlopeAfter1004").value     = getRandom(7, 3, 2);
    document.getElementById("ToneSlopeAfter2804").value     = "0.00";
    document.getElementById("ToneSlopeAfterNoise").value    = getRandom(7, 1, 2);
    document.getElementById("ToneSlopeAfterLb").value       = getRandom(79, 70, 2);
    document.getElementById("ToneSlopeCotName").value       = "NA";

    document.getElementById("ToneSlopeTn").focus();
}

function closingComments() {
    document.getElementById("flatRateJacks").value = "0";
    document.getElementById("rewiredJacks").value  = "0";

    document.getElementById("tripNo").click();
    document.getElementById("marketMass").click();
    document.getElementById("custTypeRes").click();
    document.getElementById("pairChangeNo").click();
    document.getElementById("tempDropNo").click();
    document.getElementById("goodCbrYes").click();

    document.getElementById("jobCloseComments").focus();
    window.scrollTo(0, 5000);
}

function getRandom(max, min, tenths) {
    var result = min + (Math.random() * (max - min + 1));
    return result.toFixed(tenths);
}
```

On another note, I have to refresh the page for this to load.  I'll make another post if I have to, but I'm wondering how to detect this page loading.  It's all on our secure network and you get here by clicking a button.

Comment: Have you tried creating the button as an element and then appending it to the mydiv?

Comment: I haven't yet.  I know how to create an element, but how do I append it to the div?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var btn=document.createElement("button");
btn.id='mapButton';
btn.value='Google Maps';
btn.addEventListener("click", googleMaps(address), false);
myDiv.appendChild(btn);
```

But side note... I noticed your tag has errors which is probably your problem. There is no `<input>` with `type='button'` it should be `<button id="mapButton" value="Google Maps">`

Hope that helps.

Comment: No!  [Setting `onclick` like that is a bad idea!](http://commons.oreilly.com/wiki/index.php/Greasemonkey_Hacks/Getting_Started#Pitfall_.232:_Event_Handlers).

Comment: @Brock could you explain your reasoning?

Comment: @SnareChops, if you read the link I gave, it explains it pretty well.

Comment: @Brock Ahh... Thank you, I will update my answer accordingly, so that others won't be mislead

Comment: Any ideas why it is acting as if I clicked the button as soon as the page loads?  Using the code exactly as above.

Comment: You need to add the code to the `function addButton()` but why the `click` event is firing without you clicking the button first is a mystery. Try setting the last parameter in the `.addEventListener()` to `false` Does that help?

Comment: Should have mentioned that I did change it to false as well, but still acts the same.

Comment: Another note: The `btn.addEventListener("click", googleMaps(address), false);` and the `document.getElementById ("mapButton").addEventListener ("click", googleMaps(address), false);` are doing the same thing. I'm sure you removed one of them already though. Can you edit your post above with an update to show the code you have now to see where the problem could be?

Comment: Edited above code, and added another problem as well; although the first issue is my focus right now.

Comment: I also had to change it to an input element instead of a button because it was sizing incorrectly.  Same issue on both of them though.

Comment: @Cameron That is very odd that the `<button>` tag doesn't size correctly compared to a `<input>`. Might be an issue in the CSS (we can tackle that problem after we solve this one of course) If you would like the page to display new data without having to refresh then we would use AJAX to asynchronously get the new data and insert it onto the page. This is quite easy and we could go over that too. So just to be clear what are the current problems (1: Button `onclick` triggers when page loads. 2: `<button>` won't size correctly. 3: Page have to refresh page for content to load.) correct?

Comment: correct on 1 and 3.  The button is not really a big deal because <input> works just as well as the button if we could fix issue #1.  I should also mention that eventhough it is firing on the page load, clicking it thereafter seems to do nothing.  Same thing when using <button>

Comment: @Cameron So when the page loads `googleMaps(address)` fires which calls `GM_openInTab` which I'm assuming opens another tab with the address lookup page in it? So page loads and automatically opens new tab correct?

Comment: Yes, I can see the button and then the function fires.  I went ahead and posted my entire script as well.